# I can't bind a 3d object to the center of another object

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

I'm developing kind of solar system. Planets move around the Sun, and different stuff on the Earth (like trees and flowers is imported using interactive mesh) around the center of the planet.

I tried to shift the center with .add(calibration) where calibration is a variable which holds the value of supposed wrong shift

```
//shape is javafx Shape3D[] and it is set to interactive mesh ModelImporter. 
Shape3D[] stuffOnEarth = Shape3dConstructor.getShape3D(name);//works fine. adds a 3d object to the scene. You can imagine it as an array of Sphere
for (Shape3D part : stuffOnEarth) {
   var movement = new PathTransition(new Duration(DAY), new Circle(earth.RADIUS+distanceFromSurface), part);
   movement.play();         
}
StackPane stuffPane = new StackPane();
stuffPane.translateXProperty().bind(Earth.translateXProperty());  stuffPane.translateYProperty().bind(Earth.translateYProperty().add(calibration));
stuffPane.getChildren().addAll(stuffOnEarth);

    // Earth is a javafx sphere that rotates around the Sun 
    Sphere earth = new Sphere(RADIUS);
    var rotate = new PathTransition(new Duration(YEAR), new Circle(distanceFromTheSun), earth);
    rotate.play();
```

But the stuff is not rotating around the center of the Earth, instead it moves around I don't know what.

Comment: Post a [mcve] (use `Sphere`s instead of imported objects). I don't see anything rotating around anything.

Comment: Please read the link. This is not an MCVE.

Comment: I guess my code is wrong from the very beginning. Objects  should rotate around the center of the Earth, Spheres and etc work fine, but when it comes to objects imported with interactive mesh, the center shift to an unknown point

Comment: I think the problem is in interactive mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To bind a 3d object to the surface of the Earth I did the following: I created a Sphere and a pathtransition with the path represented with a circle of Earth radius; then I bound the 3d object to the center Sphere. This was the solution.

And the real problem was that id didn't use the correct way to scale objects object.getTransforms().add(new Scale(x, y, z);